# Activity not starting from background automatically

Tags: android, flutter, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I'm trying to start `MainActivity` automatically after getting firebase push notification in background but activity not starting. Here is my code:

**firebase push data payload:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "title":"this is push title",
        "body": "this is push body",
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
    },

    "to": ""

 }
```

**FirebaseMessegingService onMessageReceived method:**

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
      if (isApplicationForeground(this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_REMOTE_MESSAGE);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_REMOTE_MESSAGE, remoteMessage);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
      }
      else {
        notification(backgroundContext, remoteMessage);
      }

    }

    private void notification(Context context, RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
              .getActivity(context, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

      String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
      String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

      String channelId = context.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
      Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
      NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
              new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                      .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                      .setContentTitle(title)
                      .setContentText(body)
                      .setAutoCancel(true)
                      .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                      .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                      .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                      .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                              .bigText(body))
                      .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
              .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
          notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
      }

      if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
      }


      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityOpener.class);
      pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, myIntent,0);
      alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }
  }
```

**Activity opener BroadcastReceiver:**

```
public class ActivityOpener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "ActivityOpener";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent wakeIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        wakeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(wakeIntent);
        Log.d(TAG, "activity opener");
    }
}
```

This `BroadcastReceiver` triggering  in background after push but activity not opening. My current device os version `Android 9`.

**Is there anything I'm missing?**